# Trying to batch merge nodes that are the same

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have about 4.7 million "entity nodes." Many of these are duplicate entities. I want to merge the entities that are the same and keep the relationship(s) between those new combined entities and the things they are connected to in place. I wrote the below query to try and do this, but it does not seem to be working. Any assistance with this is greatly appreciated.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  'MATCH (e:Entity) 
   WITH e.name AS name, e.entity_type AS type, collect(e) as nodes 
   CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodes, {
    properties: { 
     author_id:"combine",
     author_name:"combine",
     entity_hash:"combine",
     entity_type:"combine",
     forum_id:"combine",
     name:"discard",
     post_id:"combine",
     thread_id:"combine"
   }
  }) YIELD node 
  RETURN count(node) AS new_node_count',
  '', 
  {batchSize:100000}
)
```

The pinwheel keeps spinning but not reduction in nodes or anything, which tells me it's hung.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use correctly the procedure `apoc.periodic.iterate`. This procedure takes 2 queries :

- the first : for creating a population of element on which you will iterate
- the second : for each element of the first query, what you want to do

So in your cae, the query should be :

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
  'MATCH (e:Entity) 
   WITH e.name AS name, e.entity_type AS type, collect(e) as nodes 
   RETURN nodes',
   'CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodes, {
    properties: { 
     author_id:"combine",
     author_name:"combine",
     entity_hash:"combine",
     entity_type:"combine",
     forum_id:"combine",
     name:"discard",
     post_id:"combine",
     thread_id:"combine"
   }
  })',
  {batchSize:500}
)
```

Moreover I have decrease the size of the batch to 500, because if you have a lot of identicals nodes, `500` is cool (or `1000` but not `100000` otherwise you will have some OOM).

To see the perf of this query, you can previously test the first query to see if it is fast.

Comment: Thank you! I think it was working and then I got this error.  {
  "Query cannot conclude with CALL (must be RETURN or an update clause) (line 1, column 55 (offset: 54))
"UNWIND {_batch} AS _batch WITH _batch.nodes AS nodes  CALL apoc.refactor.mergeNodes(nodes, {"
                                                       ^": 2991
} I then added ` }
  }) YIELD node',
  {batchSize:500}
)
` to the end and it seemed to be working. However, I am now getting that same error again.